# Build failed LaunchPad "Dependency wait on lgw01-31"

Tags: ppa, launchpad

I have got a PPA on LaunchPad and a pack which depends on `gawk (>= 1:4.1.1+dfsg-1)` (this is set in the control file). But when uploading the `.change` file to LaunchPad with `dput` I get this error:

[image: Dependency wait on lgw01-31]

So why is the build failing when it doesn't for any of my other packages of this project? And how can I fix it?

This is the version for Trusty, the versions for Utopic and Vivid build fine. And this is the page with the error message on it: https://launchpad.net/~secretiveppc/+archive/ubuntu/anti-sr/+build/7126328

Comment: Can you give us a link to the page? We might be able to better determine what's going on if we can view the buildlog. Also "lgw01-31" is the name of the machine that attempted to build the package.

Comment: @NathanOsman: Ok, I have added the information to my question which you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are attempting to build the package for Trusty (Ubuntu 14.04), but your `control` file requires a newer version of `gawk` than is currently available for Trusty:

- the latest version of `gawk` available for Trusty is [1:4.0.1+dfsg-2.1ubuntu2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gawk)
- your `control` file is requesting a version >= `1:4.1.1+dfsg-1`

The solution is to either change your `control` file to require an earlier version (assuming you aren't depending on a feature introduced in a later version) or backport the newer `gawk` version.